# How to remove Lubuntu LXDE applications when upgrading to Lubuntu LXQt?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, lubuntu, 19.04

I recently upgraded from Lubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 then to 19.04 using the inbuilt software updater. But I think with the upgrade some of the apps from 18.04 were retained. For example, there are two terminals in the image below:

[image: This is the image]

Comment: Yes currently you'll have LXDE and LXQt desktops (at the greeter or login screen you can select which you want to use). The Lubuntu team recommended a re-install when you upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 18.10 (first LXQt)  for a number of reasons, of which this was one. I would check out this feature before you remove them (just to see if you'd use it; I decided to keep LXDE on my box)   https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-released/

Answer (score 3):

The switch from LXDE (18.04) to LXQt (18.10) was a huge one, and the Lubuntu team recommended a clean install rather than upgrade for a number of reasons

> The most major and notable problem is that upgrading Lubuntu from
>   18.04 to 18.10 causes a fair amount of issues. Therefore, we are not officially supporting this upgrade path at this time, however we have
>   prepared a page in the Lubuntu Manual which can help address the
>   problems that arise after the upgrade.

https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-released/

The Lubuntu team however wrote notes, for their official manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/D/upgrading.html)

Please note: The manual now reflects 19.04 which is the latest, but the detail you specifically asked about had this written

> After the installation, reboot into the new 18.10 system. You be
>   greeted by a new login screen that is the SDDM display manager and a
>   notification that this is now your first time running LXQt Power
>   Management.
>
> Many of the old applications will not be removed. Newer and often
>   times more featureful, Qt-based applications with the same
>   functionality are installed during the upgrade. Having many
>   unnecessary applications could bloat your system and isn't the true
>   Lubuntu experience, so uninstalling them may be a good idea. The
>   following command will remove unnecessary applications:
>
> .. code::
>
> `sudo apt purge leafpad file-roller galculator gpicview xpad xfburn
>   simple-scan mtpaint pidgin sylpheed transmission-gtk abiword evince
>   gnumeric audacious gnome-mpv guvcview pcmanfm gdebi lxterminal
>   hardinfo lightdm lxpanel lxsession obconf gnome-software
>   gnome-disk-utility system-config-printer-gnome lxhotkey-gtk synaptic
>   update-manager lxpolkit lxtask lxshortcut blueman usb-creator-gtk
>   evince-common`
>
> To remove uneeded dependencies enter the following command:
>
> .. code::
>
> `sudo apt autoremove`

*I'm copying this from the Lubuntu team's phab infrastructure, sorry I don't know how to navigate it as a normal user.  I know the manual will show release specific pages in the future, but I don't know if it's already been implemented and or to operate it sorry.  It could be this wasn't published officially because of the decision to not-support 18.04 to 18.10 upgrades*

Comment: https://phab.lubuntu.me/source/manual/browse/18.10/source/D/upgrading.rst