# How do I fix "unresolvable problem occured while calculating the upgrade" (from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04)

Tags: upgrade, updates, lubuntu, do-release-upgrade

It occurred while upgrading from Lubuntu 18.04.05 LTS to Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

**Could not calculate the upgrade**

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was likely caused by:

- Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
  Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge
  package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and
  try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

I have only installed Steam, Pycharm Community, Python 3.8, Google Chrome, and Zoom on this PC.

My specs:
Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU E2180 @ 2.00GHz 1 physical processor; 2 threads; 2 cores
Intel Family G33/G31 graphics
RAM: 2028964KiB (2GB)
Ubuntu Distro Flavor: Lubuntu
Ubuntu Version: 18.04.05 LTS

I am a newb to Ubuntu. So please help me with a simple solution. I have been waiting for this update for so long. ( I don't know how to use ppa-purge and what it is )

Comment: To get a clean upgrade, you should remove 3rd party software (all PPA & other non-Ubuntu repository software), *release-upgrade*, reboot, then re-add back the 3rd party software. That was what the message was telling you, you have unofficial (3rd party) packages that have interfered with the upgrade (usually because they increase packages to new versions than originally supplied).   However Lubuntu (LXDE for 18.04) differs to Lubuntu (18.10 or later) so see next comment

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the last Lubuntu using the LXDE desktop, and a re-install is the recommended way to upgrade that desktop. From the release notes (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) you'll note the following "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install*" so in your case I'd recommend upgrade via re-install (backup data of course first)

Comment: If you do upgrade, many clues can be found on this site, eg. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154838/how-to-remove-lubuntu-lxde-applications-when-upgrading-to-lubuntu-lxqt https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085526/is-there-any-official-guidance-to-upgrading-from-lubuntu-18-04-lts-lxde-to-l  however they were from 18.04 to 18.10 (18.10 being first LXQt release; there are 5 now) and documentation wasn't updated as support for upgrade was dropped.  (source link [Oct 2018] found in comment on my answer)

Comment: Check this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1306361/110089

Answer (score 0):

`ppa-purge` is a package that you can install,

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
```

then, read the documentation (`man ppa-purge`) to see (if) it can help you.